# Multiple Python-Scripts (Turtlebot2 / Kobuki) in kobuki_node

Tags: roslaunch, turtlebot2, turtlebot, multiple, parallel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have multiple **python scripts** for several tasks. Let's assume: The first one is for driving a certain distance with a given speed. Another one is for image processing purpose (marker detection).
A third could be used to find a docking station and so on...

Everything is running on a Jetson TK1 (ubuntu 14.04 - Linux4Tegra) => ros indigo with a poor Turtlebot2 setup (I don't use the depth camera). On the Jetson TK1 I copied the kobuki_node to my catkin workspace and added a camera node to the kobuki nodelet (gscam) via launchfile. For running I start minimal.launch and call python scrips by command: rosrun kobuki_node mypython.py. It's possible to call "driveDistance.py" and then in parallel run the image processing routine and so on.

Now I want to put everything together like a state machine.
For this I tried to write a nohup bash script, starting each script in the background till it ends by itself or killing by process id. But hey, I think with some help I can find a better solution.
Can we?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273811/multiple-python-scripts-(turtlebot2-/-kobuki)-in-kobuki_node/) by [glukon](https://answers.ros.org/users/31987/glukon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're looking to add some *coordination* to your system.

See [wiki/flexbe](http://wiki.ros.org/flexbe) or its precursor [wiki/smach](http://wiki.ros.org/smach) to get started.

Other possibilities: [py_trees_ros](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-software-release-py-trees/2046) (very nice), [pi_trees](http://wiki.ros.org/pi_trees), [behavior_tree](http://wiki.ros.org/behavior_tree) and [decision_making](http://wiki.ros.org/decision_making) (bit old perhaps).

If you search around, you'll probably find some more alternatives, but this should get you started.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-23**:
Note: your bash scripts (and you) essentially implemented a form of manual coordination. I'd recommend to get into the automated varieties as supported by the frameworks I linked to. It'll be a bit of a learning curve, but much more flexible, maintainable and scalable.

**Comment by [glukon](https://answers.ros.org/users/31987/glukon/) on 2017-10-23**:
Thanks so far! Since I'm using a virtual machine for devel, ros master is running on the Jetson TK1 and the project yet is pretty small. I don't need a huge tool, and I don't have time for doing research and so on... Hope you get me at this point. Any ideas which one I should start with?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-23**:
I'm not sure I follow: how does that factor in when modelling your behaviour with the proper tools / infrastructure?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-23**:\

> I don't need a huge tool, and I don't have time for doing research and so on..

this was not part of your original question, so I just listed some frameworks / modelling tools I know about.

You could probably very quickly try out `flexbe`: it's well documented and has nice examples.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-23**:
But anything more structured than a set of shell scripts will probably require *some* time to get into. I think that's inevitable.

**Comment by [glukon](https://answers.ros.org/users/31987/glukon/) on 2017-10-23**:
Well, I have no idea about the tools you mentioned beeing used for behaviour modelling. To make it a bit more clear, which one is easy? Which one would cost the most time reading and going through tutorials?

**Comment by [glukon](https://answers.ros.org/users/31987/glukon/) on 2017-10-23**:
Sorry for edit! Then I will try starting with flexbe :-) Thanks a lot!!